# Django using a modelform to update an instance of model

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following model in Django which I use to store data about medicines.

```
class Medicine(models.Model):
    Medicine_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    User_Associated = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Tablets_In_Box = models.IntegerField()
    Dose_in_mg = models.IntegerField()
    Dose_Tablets = models.IntegerField()
    Number_Of_Boxes = models.IntegerField()
    Last_Collected = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Medicine_Name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tracker-home')
```

I am trying to create a model form where a user can update the last collection of one of their medicines. Here is what I began with.

```
class CollectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Medicine
        fields = ['Medicine_Name', 'Number_Of_Boxes', 'Last_Collected']
```

I do not understand how I can call an instance of my model based on the 'Medicine_Name' from the field. In other words, I need the user to be able to select the correct medicine from a dropdown menu, and then the form must update the 'Last_Collected', and 'Numer_Of_Boxes' fields on my Medicine model.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

It seems this contains relevant information, but I struggle to see how to use it in this instance. How can I correctly get the instance of the medicine form I need, based on the user input in the form? Furthermore how can I use the save method in my views to make sure the database gets updated correctly?

**EDIT** Added view for the form:

```
def update(request, pk):
    
    instance = Medicine.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CollectionForm(user=request.user, instance=instance, data=request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.User_Associated = request.user
            instance.save()
    else:
        form = CollectionForm() 
    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'tracker/medicine_collection.html', context )
```

Answer (score 1):

****EDIT**

views:

```
def update(request, pk):
    instance = Medicine.objects.get(id=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CollectionForm(instance=instance, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.User_Associated = request.user
            instance.save()
        return redirect ('/')
        ....
```

Comment: I'm getting an error " 
local variable 'instance' referenced before assignment" when trying to submit my form. Do I need to define my instance in the form, based on the medicine_name ?

Comment: I think referencing the actual object like in the above edit should do the trick.

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. I don't think adding pk as an argument of update is valid. I changed it to ' def update(request, *args, **kwargs): ' but then I get 'pk is not defined'. How do I get the primary key based on what the user selects from the dropdown menu?

Comment: Can you send a snippet of your views.py?

Answer (score 0):

This is based on updating the instance of the specific user. This tutorial helpt me achieve the same thing.

https://youtu.be/EX6Tt-ZW0so

Comment: This seems like a slightly different use case though. I only want one 'update' button on my webpage, not one per field of my Medicine model. I don't understand where I will get the primary key from in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a different approach (class based views - UpdateView) I just learned here on SO. Did not test it but I think its a step in the right direction.

```
class UpdateMedicine(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Medicine  #call the model you need to update
    fields = ['Medicine_Name', 'Number_Of_Boxes', 'Last_Collected'] #specify the fields you need to update
    template_name_suffix = 'medicine_update_form' #specify the template where the update form is living

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(
            user=self.request.user, #get the current logged in user
            instance=get_object_or_404(Medicine, pk=self.kwargs['pk']) #get the pk of the instance
        )
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.medicine = get_object_or_404(Medicine, slug=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super().form_valid(form) #saves the updates to the instance 

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('medicine-collection') #name of the url where your 'tracker/medicine_collection.html is living
```

Link the appropriate templates and urls to the above example and try some things yourself.

Link to the django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Good luck!